# Difficulty in understanding the typescript array syntax of a the Chart JS data structure

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

For my (Angular) Typescript project, I managed to create a scatter chart. It works, but I like to understand the following array definition (I created this definition using Webstorm's 'Specify type explicitly' functionality):

```
let chartArray: ({ x: number; y: number })[] = [];
```

Usage:

```
chartArray.push({x: xValues[i], y: yValues[i]});
```

I have no clue what the '({ ... })' before the '[]' means. The documentation only showed me tuples, generics, for example.

Comment: `{ x: number; y: number }` is just an object with `x` and `y` property, each of which a number. And you have an array of them.

Comment: it's a way to say to typeScript that the variable chartArray is an array of object each element of the array are object that has two properties `x` and `y` (both numbers)

Comment: It's the type definition of each element of the array. I'd say using a [TS interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) would make things easier to understand. Eg. for `interface Point { x: number; y: number; }`, the array definition would become `let chartArray: Point[] = [];`.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing a light on my question! The interface definition makes more sense to me. For me, the confusing part was the brackets around the object definition. Is it a 'cast' thing? Like: something = (string)5;

Comment: No, just grouping. `{foo: number}` is the same as `({foo: number})`. However, the latter is clearer if you also add other notation `[]` at the end to mark it as an array `({foo: number})[]`. By the way, there is no casting in TS, there is *type assertion* where you directly tell the compiler to treat something as another type. The type assertion syntax is `<number> x` or `x as number` to tell the compiler to treat `x` as a number (they are identical). However, type assertion will not *change* (cast) the value to a different type. If `x` is `"five"` it will remain a string at runtime.

Comment: Ah, grouping! You are absolutely right. I feel like a real greenhorn now ;-)